# posting data to database from session variables of logged in user

Tags: php, sql

i am getting 0 in the database table pets where pet_id should be updated to the logged in users id

any ideas please i think this something simple but im not sure.

```
<?php require 'database.php';
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$_SESSION['user_id']= $id;  
$_SESSION['user_name'] = $full_name;
$_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;
$_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
$_SESSION['session_name'] = $user_name;
$_SESSION['balance']= $balance;  
$value = 1050;
$user_id = mysql_insert_id($link);


$sql_insert1 = "INSERT into `pets`
            (`pet_id`,`value`)
            VALUES
            ('.$id','$value')";



mysql_query($sql_insert1,$link) or die("Failed" . mysql_error());

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an unnecessary period, try:

```
$sql_insert1 = "INSERT into `pets`
                (`pet_id`, `value`)
                VALUES
                ('$id', '$value')";
```

Comment: Without proper [SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php), this is **dangerously** insecure.

Comment: @tadman Actually, I would recommend a parameterized query for security.

Comment: Whenever possible, it's best to demonstrate how that might work.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, session_start(); MUST ALWAYS be the first line of your script after the <?php.

Secondly, your concat is completely wrong.

Here is a slighty more correct version, needs some testing:

```
<?php 
session_start();
require 'database.php';
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$_SESSION['user_id']= $id;  
$_SESSION['user_name'] = $full_name;
$_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;
$_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
$_SESSION['session_name'] = $user_name;
$_SESSION['balance']= $balance;  
$value = 1050;
$user_id = mysql_insert_id($link);


$sql_insert1 = "INSERT into `pets`
        (`pet_id`,`value`)
        VALUES
        ('".$id."','".$value."')";



mysql_query($sql_insert1,$link) or die("Failed" . mysql_error());

?>
```

Comment: need to check for duplicate entry's read above comment for more info

Answer (score 0):

Where does $id come from? Not from 'database.php' I assume.

Did you mean to restore the $id from the session?
Then you should write:

```
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
```

And, then if you have a $value that makes sense, your query should work:

```
$sql_insert1 = "INSERT into `pets`
                (`pet_id`, `value`)
                VALUES
                ('$id', '$value')";
```

Comment: i dont know, this is solved now but how can i check for duplicates before this insert happens as its allowing any amount of pets when there should only be 1 per user_id

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
session_start();
require 'database.php';
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
//echo $id;
//exit;
//print the value and check what you are getting here 
//i think you will get 0 here
//$_SESSION['user_id']= $id;  
$_SESSION['user_name'] = $full_name;
$_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;
$_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
$_SESSION['session_name'] = $user_name;
$_SESSION['balance']= $balance;  
$value = 1050;
$user_id = mysql_insert_id($link);


$sql_insert1 = "INSERT into `pets`
            (`pet_id`,`value`)
            VALUES
            ('.$id','$value')";



mysql_query($sql_insert1,$link) or die("Failed" . mysql_error());

?>
```

Comment: print the query before execution of mysql_query

Comment: after require statement keep the below lines like print_r($_SESSION);exit;